# Windows 10 - Automatically exit batch script

Tags: batch-file

This is my script:

```
SQLPLUS -S -M "HTML ON TABLE 'BORDER="2"'" username/pass@env @test.sql>test.html
```

After execution command prompt window stays open. How do I auto-close?

Comment: What if someone doesn't want their shell killed? This should be up to the person executing the script. If you don't want a lingering shell, just run it from a shortcut or directly from Explorer, or run it as `script.bat & exit`.

Comment: I'm the only user and I want this bat exit after execution. I try exit and some other variations but nothing helped.

Comment: If the console remains open after cmd exits, then some other process is attached to the console, probably something spawned by sqlplus.

Comment: To be honest I don't know what's happening in background. I just want somehow to force auto-closing :)

Comment: If you have Python installed, try `python -c "import os; os.kill(0, 1)" & exit`. This sends a Ctrl+Break to every process attached to the console. Most don't handle it and get immediately killed by the default handler. cmd does handle it, but the final `exit` should kill it.

Comment: I don't have Python. I give up. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 2):

After your line of code add another line, like this:

```
exit
```

or

```
tskill cmd.exe
```

I hope I can help you.

Comment: I have that line, it doesn't help :S

Comment: Try to add two other lines:

1) timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul

                 2) exit

Comment: Again stops after first line. I give up. Thx anyway.

Comment: Last try: tskill cmd.exe

Comment: I create some workaround solution. Thx for trying, br.